# Extrair Url direta do Blogger (URL Token)

Tags: php, array, api, blogger

Estou tentando extrair o URL direto do Blogger por php ou pelo código-fonte da página

a URL que eu quero extrair é:

```
https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=3506042769269f95
```

a URL direta (URL Token) que eu quero obter é:

```
https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dz0uwopNrKXORmGgs7ejV3_FJScdWnQvWz_DhYSuw8vReBV2Yhy12AAGhNWcshcza0dhVKqaiq2mgdFKG8ZPg9vQKpsU5gQVab4FzYeJTT9gMg81c679_k1TZevU2abOH8ad6Rn
```

v

```
$string = "https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=3506042769269f95";

preg_match_all('https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=', $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]); 
echo "</pre>";
```

v

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dz0uwopNrKXORmGgs7ejV3_FJScdWnQvWz_DhYSuw8vReBV2Yhy12AAGhNWcshcza0dhVKqaiq2mgdFKG8ZPg9vQKpsU5gQVab4FzYeJTT9gMg81c679_k1TZevU2abOH8ad6Rn
)
```

Ou extrair o URL pelo código fonte da página:

```
view-source:https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=3506042769269f95
```

e obter a URL token:

```
Array ( 
    [error] => O vídeo esta indisponível 
    [extract] => https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dz0uwopNrKXORmGgs7ejV3_FJScdWnQvWz_DhYSuw8vReBV2Yhy12AAGhNWcshcza0dhVKqaiq2mgdFKG8ZPg9vQKpsU5gQVab4FzYeJTT9gMg81c679_k1TZevU2abOH8ad6Rn 
)
```

OBS: não quero extrair >> `"AD6v5dz0uwopNrKXORmGgs7ejV3_FJScdWnQvWz_DhYSuw8vReBV2Yhy12AAGhNWcshcza0dhVKqaiq2mgdFKG8ZPg9vQKpsU5gQVab4FzYeJTT9gMg81c679_k1TZevU2abOH8ad6Rn"`

e sim >>

```
"https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dz0uwopNrKXORmGgs7ejV3_FJScdWnQvWz_DhYSuw8vReBV2Yhy12AAGhNWcshcza0dhVKqaiq2mgdFKG8ZPg9vQKpsU5gQVab4FzYeJTT9gMg81c679_k1TZevU2abOH8ad6Rn"
```

DA URL:

```
"https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=3506042769269f95"
```

- Alguma idéia de como posso fazer isso?
- Toda ajuda é bem vinda!
- Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A url `https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=3506042769269f95` era de um redirecionador da Google que infelizmente não existe mais, os novos links estão vindo no modelo `www.blogger.com/video.g?token` com o player do YouTube, existe um método de obter o link do(s) vídeo(s), e suas qualidades com o `preg_match_all` do PHP, mas resolvi fazer de um jeito um pouco mais fácil, mas a parte falha é que usará o Ip do servidor para gerar o link, e caso tente repassar pelo do cliente ,o servidor do vídeo vai retornar não encontrado, segue abaixo:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['token'])){
    $data = file_get_contents('https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token='.$_REQUEST['token']);
    $data = preg_replace('/<\s*style.+?<\s*\/\s*style.*?>/si', ' ', $data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = str_replace("var VIDEO_CONFIG = ", "", $data);
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data;
    unset($data);
}
```

Isso te retornará um JSON que fica na tag script dentro da tag head na pagina, no passo a passo oque eu fiz foi:
1° Pegar a pagina em texto.
2° Remover a tag style e todo seu conteúdo
3° Remover todas as tags restantes mas deixando seu conteúdo
4° O conteúdo restante que sobra é apenas de uma tag javascript que fica na tag head onde está o JSON
5° Removi a variável javascript que apontava ao JSON
6° Decodifiquei o JSON transformando em um array e também decodificando caracteres especiais como: \u0026 = & e etc...
7° Transformei novamente em array
8° Escrevi o texto
9° Limpei a variável

Para ser um pouco mais rápido:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['token'])){
    echo json_encode(json_decode(str_replace("var VIDEO_CONFIG = ", "", strip_tags(preg_replace('/<\s*style.+?<\s*\/\s*style.*?>/si', ' ', file_get_contents('https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token='.$_REQUEST['token'])))), true));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Estou procurando algo parecido para acessar os videos do blogger, mas dese que a função antiga parou de funcionar só encontrei esse site que consegue acessar os videos com essa URL  https://tudogostoso.blog/make/check/?list=e6dac2f91a67e518  -  vc saberia me dizer como ele consegue acesssar o video com essa url apenas mudando a ID do video?

Comment: Alguns sites tem a API interna para pegar esses videos (ou ate diretamente do Google Drive), que eles mantem atualizadas, mas para descobrir como o fez só contatando o dono do site, isso se ele quiser lhe repassar o conhecimento

Comment: Não consigo informações do dono do site, mas é possivel ver a API que foi usada mudando as últimas letras apos list=   que a api aparece.  mas ainda não cosegui decifra como faz eu fiz a pergunta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414450/acessar-conte%c3%bado-atr%c3%a1ves-de-api-blogger os dados que consegui extrair da url